# How do i get these things horizontal instead of vertical?

Tags: css, layout, drop-down-menu

http://we-live.in/city.html -- id like to see RESOURCES and EVENTS side by side bc im listing 3 more... rather than on top of one another -- can i do that within the div or do i have to redesign the layout?

```
  <div id="row1">
    <div class="wrapper">
    <h2><script type="text/javascript">
<!--
document.write('<form name="selecter1"><select name="select1" size=1>');
document.write('<option value=none>Select your destination');
document.write('<option value=none>BUILDING');
document.write('<option value="page1.html">BUILDING');
document.write('<option value="page2.html">NEIGHBORHOOD');
document.write('<option value="page 3.html">CITY');
document.write('</select>');
document.write('  <input type="button" value="Go" onclick="go1()">');
document.write('</form>');
// end hiding contents -->
</script>Resources</h2>
    <h2><script type="text/javascript">
<!--
document.write('<form name="selecter1"><select name="select1" size=1>');
document.write('<option value=none>Select your destination');
document.write('<option value=none>BUILDING');
document.write('<option value="page1.html">BUILDING');
document.write('<option value="page2.html">NEIGHBORHOOD');
document.write('<option value="page 3.html">CITY');
document.write('</select>');
document.write('  <input type="button" value="Go" onclick="go1()">');
document.write('</form>');
// end hiding contents -->
</script>Events</h2>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try a little css <h2 style="float:left"> and go from there.

Comment: thanks so much- where should i put it in the general page or in the div?-- ill go try

Comment: http://we-live.in/city.html  its moving stuff - but its moving the text not the forms